# Getting length of records in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm using the `CsvHelper` library in `C#` to read a `CSV` file like this:

```
var dataCsvFileReader = File.OpenText(inputFile);
var dataCsvReader = new CsvReader(dataCsvFileReader);
var dataRecords = dataCsvReader.GetRecords<dynamic>();

foreach(dynamic record in dataRecords){
    for(int i = 0; i < ???; i++){ //How many columns are there in the record???
        Console.WriteLine($"Record {i} value is: {record[i]}");
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, my problem is that I don't know how many columns there are in the record. Since I don't know the structure of the data before parsing it (the CSV files I have as input are always different), how can I find out how many columns there are? I tried to query `dataCsvReader.Context.ColumnCount` but that always returns `0`.

Comment: @xdtTransform I've seen plenty of apps (SSMS for one) that allow for import of undefined CSV; where initially the number of columns won't be known; where the user picks which columns to import.  Tools that work on concrete types at compile-time probably aren't useful

Comment: @xdtTransform: you're wrong, CsvHelper supports parsing CSV wihtout mapping it to a class, by using a dynamic object, as shown in line 3 of my code. Also, why do you find having variable input strange? For example, how do you think a CSV editor utility would work if knowing the data structure in advance was required? :D

Comment: @xdtTransform if you have a "malformed file" then what's the point of your compile-time class definition?

Comment: @MickyD, Well if no class is define then everything is malformed. I will give a clear exemple when I get out of meeting. with `var propsValues = dataRecords.Select(x => (IDictionary<string, object>)x);` from the expando in dynnamic. It will be clearer.

Comment: @xdtTransform: the file being "malformed" is a VERY DIFFERENT thing to not knowing the data structure in advance. In my case, the file is always well-formed, it comes from an analytics engine that is quite robust and will not output malformed files. I just don't know in advance the structure of the data (how many columns) but that is perfectly normal, and easily solved by using the `.GetRecords<dynamic>` method of CsvHelper

Comment: @xdtTransform: who said I know "nothing"? Why are you assuming that? I only said I don't know the columns count/names. But I know the delimiter, as the engine that generates the data always uses commas "," to delimit data.

Comment: @xdtTransform: no problem friend, thanks for your answer, I gave it a +1. Cheers.

Comment: Ever figure out why ColumnCount is always zero? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert each record to `List`

```
using (TextReader dataCsvFileReader = File.OpenText(inputFile))
{
    using (CsvReader dataCsvReader = new CsvReader(dataCsvFileReader))
    {
        while (dataCsvReader.Read())
        {
            var dataRecord = Enumerable.ToList(dataCsvReader.GetRecord<dynamic>());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Actually, I ended up simply using `int colCount = Enumerable.Count(record);` but the concept is the same

Comment: Why not get dataCsvReader.Context.Record ?

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution listing, couting and showing the value of your dynamics CSV.
In order to read and find column, you need few informations: The Delimiter, the encodage, if the file has an header. Without those there is no way to achieve this. 
In the following exemple I use default value for header and encodage.

Here the idea is to handle convert the csv to `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. The `using` have no treatement to free the `StreamReader` asap.

```
List<IDictionary<string, object>> dataRecords  ;

using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
    dataRecords = csvReader.GetRecords<dynamic>()
                           .Select(x =>  (IDictionary<string, object>)x) 
                           .ToList();
}

foreach (var record in dataRecords)
{
    // Print number of columns, and columns collection.
    Console.WriteLine($"-> {record.Count} Columns {{{string.Join(", ", record.Keys)}}}");
    foreach (var property in record.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\t{0} : {1}", property, record[property]));
    }
}
```

To avoid possible performance bottleneck boxing you can use a Dictionary like :

```
.Select(x => new Dictionary<string, object>((IDictionary<string, object>)x))
```

Result :

```
-> 43 Columns {Method, Job, AnalyzeLaunchVariance,...}  
    Method : DiffOriginalNoAny  
    Job : Default  
    AnalyzeLaunchVariance : False  

-> 43 Columns {Method, Job, AnalyzeLaunchVariance,...}  
   Method : DiffOriginal  
   Job : Default  
   AnalyzeLaunchVariance : False
```

Comment: thanks, this is another solution that works, didn't know the dynamic record implemented IDictionary in the background.

Comment: Nice answer buddy

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            while (await csv.ReadAsync())
            {
                var count = csv.Context.Record.Length; // get the length of the record
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should remember to do, is reading the csv before accessing it:

```
var dataCsvFileReader = File.OpenText(inputFile);
var dataCsvReader = new CsvReader(dataCsvFileReader);
dataCsvReader.Read();
var dataRecords = dataCsvReader.GetRecords<dynamic>();
```

I'd recommend `using` clause here:

```
var dataCsvFileReader = File.OpenText(inputFile);
using(CsvReader dataCsvReader = new CsvReader(dataCsvFileReader))
{
    //read before accessing csv file
    dataCsvReader.Read();
    //count for columns
    var count = dataCsvReader.Context.ColumnCount;
    var dataRecords = dataCsvReader.GetRecords<dynamic>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I just tried it and `count` is always `0`. The records are read correctly (I can see the header and data if I inspect the records with the debugger) but can't seem to get a column count. Also, the CSVHelper documentation states "When using GetRecords, Read is automatically called for you", so I don't think calling .Read() is helping there.